# Well ordered sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

$(X,\le)$ is totally ordered. How do you prove that if every non empty countable subset of $X$ is well ordered then $(X,\le)$ is well ordered?

Comment: Not. Consider $X = \mathbb{R}$ with the usual ordering. It's totally ordered, but not well-ordered. On the other hand, every nonempty finite subset _is_ well-ordered.

Comment: This is false right, consider $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Why do you tag all your questions with [general-topology]? What purpose does that serve?

Comment: @AsafKaragila because i came across this in my topology lecture

Comment: It's a fair call on the tag, Rajinda. However, the tags are intended to convey the topic being discussed, rather than the class in which it was encountered. Many people (including myself) make that mistake early on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now you have the correct conditions, the proof goes like this:

Let $Y\subseteq X$ be non-empty. If it is not well ordered then it is uncountable. Let $y_1\in Y$, we know $y_1$ is not the minimal element of $Y$, hence by totality there is $y_2\neq y_1\in Y$ such that $y_2\leq y_1$.

Repeat this process inductively and you have an infinite chain of distinct elements

$$y_1\geq y_2\geq y_3\geq\ldots$$
This is a countable set and so it is well ordered, however it is clear that there is no smallest element. A contradiction.

Hence $Y$ is well-ordered.

Answer (score 2):

*The below answers an [older revision](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/433650/2) of this question; the current revision (4) is answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420389/is-a-totally-ordered-set-well-ordered-provided-that-its-countable-subsets-are).*

---

This can't be done, for the following reason:

**Exercise:** Every finite totally ordered set is well-ordered.

Any finite subset of a totally ordered set is also totally ordered, hence well-ordered.

Therefore, the truth of your conjecture would imply that every totally ordered is well-ordered. But consider $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: It should be non empty countable subsets. I made a change to the question. Does it affect your answer?

Comment: Yes. But your adapted question has been asked before (as pointed out by Asaf Karagila) [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420389/is-a-totally-ordered-set-well-ordered-provided-that-its-countable-subsets-are).